# Is it possible to list multiple ID's in a function, that will not trigger a .hide function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

Got a problem with my slide in menu. Check the my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wcgffsh/2/) here.
At the moment the slide-in menu closes, whenever clicked on everything else than the menu itself. The problem is, that the menu closes, when i click the text. I would like to perhaps list more ID's inside the same function, something like this;

```
if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in,text')
```

My script:

```
 var isOpened = false;
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in') {
        $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
        isOpened = false;
        $("#button").show();
      } else if(!isOpened && e.target.id=='button'){
        $("#slide-in").addClass("active");
        isOpened = true;
        $("#button").hide;
      }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$(e).target.is("#slide-in, #text")` returns a boolean `true` if the element matches one of the "id" values. Or you could just use the `||` operator and two explicit comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of checking for all the `id`s, check for existence of parent with `id` as `slide-in`

```
if(isOpened && e.target.id!='slide-in') {
    if(!$(e.target).parents('#slide-in').length) {
        $("#slide-in").removeClass("active");
        isOpened = false;
        $("#button").show();
    }
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wcgffsh/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array and `indexOf`

```
['slide-in', 'text'].indexOf(e.target.id) === -1
```

Might I suggest that you add a class to the elements you don't want it to apply to?

```
!$(this).is('.someClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#slide-in {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
  display:none;
}
```

and add this inside the `.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#button").click(function(){
         $("#slide-in").show(300);
       })
       $("#slide-in").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(300);
       });

     });
```

and if you want more real use this.
in your `css` change this class like this

```
#slide-in {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 10;
      top: 0;
      width: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #eee;
      border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
      display:none;
    }
```

for your `js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#button").click(function(){
           $("#slide-in").animate({width: "300px"});
          });
         $("#slide-in").click(function(){
           $(this).animate({width: "0px"});
         });
     });
```